# Cast extended view to view layoutinflater

Tags: java, android, android-layout

What I want to do is to be able to have my own custom control that will have some properties on it. For that I'm extending an existing View (RelativeView) and create my own view. The problem is that when I try to get an relative view from an xml layout via inflater I get java lang class cast exeption. How can I avoid that ?

```
MyRelativeView control = (MyRelativeView) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.something, null, false);
```

MyRelativeView extends RelativeLayout and the inflated view is an relativelayout. Why I get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to controls.MyRelativeView
```

Comment: Basic, but is your @+id/something in the xml really a `MyRelativeView` ?

Comment: Show your `R.layout.something`

Comment: No. @+id/something is an RelativeLayout. If I put it as MyRelativeView in editor mode I can see a blank layout.

Comment: **"No. @+id/something is an RelativeLayout."** : So what makes you think you can cast a `RelativLayout` to your `MyRelativeView`? The `ClassCastException` is telling you everything and as you haven't posted any significant code or your layout file it'll be very difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: "what makes you think you can cast a RelativLayout to your MyRelativeView": the fact that MyRelativeView extend RelativeLayout.
Here is my R.layout.something http://pastebin.com/eWnvvDAk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout file should have your custom view in it, your view extends relativeview, but relativeview is not a myrelativeview. It should be something like this instead:

```
<com.example.customviews.myRelativeView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     custom:showText="true"
     custom:labelPosition="left" 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Some text"
           android:paddingTop ="4dp"
           android:paddingBottom="4dp"
           android:id="@+id/textViewOne"
        />


    <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Some text"
           android:paddingTop ="4dp"
           android:paddingBottom="4dp"
           android:id="@+id/textViewTwo"
        />
    </com.example.customviews.myRelativeView>
```